# how to add links and images in text field of django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am using django to create a blog. In my model I am using a text field for my blog content. But I am unable to insert any image or a clickable link. How to add links(clickable) and insert images?

Comment: Did you register your model in `admin.py`?

Answer (score 1):

```
{% block body %}

{% for blog in blog %}

    <h1>{{blog.title}}</h1>

{{blog.text|safe|linebreaks}}

    <br>
    <h6>{{blog.user}}</h6>
    <br>
    <br>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: for the text field use safe filter :)

Answer (score 0):

there is no thing like clickable link in Database.you can put link as text and while importing it to your HTML use , and for Images there are two options. either you put your image path name in database or change TextField in models to FileField.